# Whats the best way to get multiple sites to connect to a central server?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp-server

So lets say that there's 4 sites: orange, blue, yellow, and green. ([screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm5Ow.jpg))

Site 1 (orange) is where the central server would be located. this server has AD,DNS,and DHCP servers.  whats the most optimal way i can get the other 3 sites to connect to the central server?

Playing around with the packet tracer program i was able to come up with something (see screenshot). is this feasible?

if not, can you tell me what is it i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is by passing the traffic through a VPN tunnel, linking the sites virtually together with each of the sites having a different gateway to go out of the internet to avoid overloading one sites internet connection.